# Where to find logs/information about unattended-upgrades (apt)?

Tags: security, apt, upgrade, dpkg, software-updates

**Where can I find infos about when the unattend updates/upgrades run and what ist done (or IF something was done)?**

I want to enable the unattended-upgrades (for security updates) on a debian virtual server and, yeah, on my RaspberryPi, too.

Do I have to search the `/var/log/apt` -logs for infos about WHAT was installed and `/var/log/syslog` about infos WHEN there was an action?

I see no CRON entry for when the update-process will run and the configs `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/20auto-upgrades` and `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/50unattended-upgrades` don't tell me either.

---

> Solution (credits to @bahamut): 
>   `sudo cat  /var/log/unattended-upgrades/unattended-upgrades.log`

```
2016-12-22 06:35:26,489 INFO Initial whitelisted packages: 
2016-12-22 06:35:26,489 INFO script for unattended-upgrades is executed
2016-12-22 06:35:26,489 INFO allowed sources are: ['origin=Debian,codename=jessie,label=Debian-Security']
2016-12-22 06:35:35,518 INFO Packages that will be upgraded: libsmbclient libtevent0 libwbclient0 python-samba samba samba-common samba-common-bin samba-dsdb-modules samba-libs samba-vfs-modules smbclient winbind
2016-12-22 06:35:35,523 INFO dpkg-protocol written to »/var/log/unattended-upgrades/unattended-upgrades-dpkg.log« 
2016-12-22 06:35:52,336 INFO all upgrades installed
```

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Unattended upgrade has its own log-file in `/var/log/unattended-upgrades/unattended-upgrades.log`.

It is policed by anacron.

```
# These lines replace cron's entries
1   5   cron.daily  run-parts --report /etc/cron.daily
7   10  cron.weekly run-parts --report /etc/cron.weekly
@monthly    15  cron.monthly    run-parts --report /etc/cron.monthly
```

Additional information on what was done is located in `/var/log/unattended-upgrades/unattended-upgrades-dpkg.log`.

Answer (score 9):

`/var/log/dpkg.log` also `/var/log/apt/history.log`

Both those log files contain timestamps and descriptions if action was taken.  if no action was taken there is no log.

automated updates runs from /`etc/cron.daily/apt` and `/etc/cron.daily/*` runs from `/etc/crontab` in the early morning.

For newer versions, updates are handled by a systemd service, `/lib/systemd/system/apt-daily.service`, invoked either by a systemd timer or by cron using `/etc/cron.daily/apt-compat`.

Comment: thanks for your answer. And when does it run - Randomly or in some kind of manner? Could I change this (ok, no practical use, I'm just curious) or should I rather call APT::Perdiodic::Unattended-Upgrade like its adviced in the manpage)

Comment: it runs from /etc/cron.daily/apt

Comment: @Jasen or from /usr/lib/apt/apt.systemd.daily in systemd environment.